# ionCube shell script gives error

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have this shell script to install ionCube loader:

```
if [[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]] ; then echo "Please run as root" ; exit 1 ; fi
echo "Welcome to this script to install the ionCube loader on CentOS!"
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
tar zxvf ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
cd  ioncube
mkdir /usr/local/ioncube
echo "Please specify which PHP version you are using (e.g.: 5.3)."
read version
cp ioncube_loader_lin_"$version".so /usr/local/ioncube
path=$(php -i|grep php.ini | awk 'NR==2{print $5}')
read path
echo "zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_"$version".so" >> "$path"
```

When I try to run it on `CentOS 6.5 Final` with this PHP version (`php -v`):

```
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2014 16:25:09) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I get the following error:

```
./ioncube.sh: line 17: : File or folder doesn't exist
```

Line 17:

```
echo "zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_"$version".so" >> "$path"
```

The error says that `$path` doesn't exist. When I try to manually run the command of `$path` (`php -i|grep php.ini | awk 'NR==2{print $5}'`), the output is:

`/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

When I try to run line 17 but replace `$path` with the actual output of the command (of course I'll replace `$version` too):

```
echo "zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_"5.3".so" >> "/usr/local/lib/php.ini"
```

The command succeeds.

I don't understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `read path`. While one line creates the `$path` variable, the next sets it to blank again:

```
## This line will set the $path variable.
path=$(php -i|grep php.ini | awk 'NR==2{print $5}')
## This one expects to read the value of $path from standard input 
## so it sets it to empty unless input is given.
read path
```

You can test this by adding `echo "$path"` after line 17 and also after the `read path`. You'll see that the second prints an empty string. You can also see that that's the problem in your error message:

```
./ioncube.sh: line 17: : File or folder doesn't exist
                     ---
                      |---------> this should be the file name
```

So, just delete the `read path` line.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. It works now, thanks :)